# Angular cli copying files out of the assets folder

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli

can some one tell my why angular cli project is copying graphic files from the assets folder into the root of the output folder?

For example I have a graphic at src/assets/background.jpg, and I reference that graphic from my src/styles.css file:

```
body {
    background-image: url(./assets/background.jpg);
}
```

Now when I build my project using:

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing=none --output-path=target/output
```

I now have the following generated output structure:

```
target/ouput
  ...
  background.jpg
  assets
    background.jpg
```

The css is refernecing the copied version of the background file and everything works, but now I have two copies of the file. How can I reference this file from assets/background.jpg so I don't get two copies?

Thanks;
David

Comment: can you show files in your dev root folder, `.angular-cli.json` `"assets"` section and what is your `@angular/cli` version ?

Comment: Have you searched your whole project for (string) background.jpg? You may be using it somewhere else.

Comment: The files in my dev root folder are:

    e2e 
    src
    target
    node_modules
    .angular-cli.json
    .editorconfig
    karma.conf.js
    package-lock.json
    package.json
    pom.xml
    protractor.conf.js
    README.md
    tsconfig.json
    tslint.json


Also, I just recently updated to angular-cli v1.2.6. I don't think I have modified the Assets sections of the .angular-cli.json file, that sections is set to:

      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],

Comment: i have the same problem any ideas?

Comment: Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

Because the idea is that *everything* you need to deploy will be in the specified output folder. Then you can deploy by copying the output folder to your server.

If the --prod build didn't copy the file, it would not be in the set of output files and would not get deployed without extra steps on your part.

Comment: It is getting deployed, "ng build" is copying my entire assets folder to the output which already includes the background.jpg file, so after it also copies that file to the output root folder is it there twice.

Comment: You answer doesnt answer the question. His problem is why Angular duplicated  the assets and uploads them twice

Comment: I read the question to be "can some one tell my why angular cli project is copying graphic files from the assets folder into the root of the output folder?"